# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "superCtor" argument must be of type function. Received undefined

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, rollup, sapper

This issue showed up after trying to install Mongoose on my sapper project

```
util.js:157
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('superCtor', 'Function', superCtor);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "superCtor" argument must be of type function. Received undefined
    at Object.inherits (util.js:157:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (<project path>\__sapper__\dev\server\server.js:140600:8)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47 {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
> Server crashed
```

*<project path> is just my project path*

I have a theory that this is caused by the bundling/minifying of the server code into a single file (`__sapper__/dev/server.js`), not sure how to fix it though.

My server rollup config, if it helps:

```js
{
    server: {
        input: { server: config.server.input().server.replace(/\.js$/, '.ts') },
        output: { ...config.server.output(), sourcemap },
        plugins: [
            replace({
                'process.browser': false,
                'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(mode),
                'module.require': 'require',
            }),
            svelte({
                generate: 'ssr',
                dev,
                preprocess,
            }),
            resolve({
                dedupe: ['svelte'],
            }),
            commonjs({
                sourceMap: !!sourcemap,
            }),
            typescript({
                noEmitOnError: !dev,
                sourceMap: !!sourcemap,
            }),
            json(),
        ],
        external: [...Object.keys(pkg.dependencies).concat(
            require('module').builtinModules || Object.keys(process.binding('natives')),
        ), 'saslprep'],

        preserveEntrySignatures: 'strict'
    },
}
```

the config is based mostly off [this template](https://github.com/babichjacob/sapper-typescript-graphql-template/blob/main/rollup.config.js)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that this will help you because I don't know what Mangose or Sapper are, but I got this error when `@google-cloud/storage` was getting imported.

The solution was to not bundle it in:

```js
nodeResolve({ 
  preferBuiltins: true, 
  browser: false, 
  resolveOnly: ['@google-cloud/storage'] 
}),
```